# Changing screen size in the browser causes issues in our application

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have a MVC web application, with no razor code, that is the views are build using only HTML and javascript code. Below is the screenshot of my screen.

Now in IE8 i am getting the following issues:

Screenshot of my screen : http://www.freeimagehosting.net/ixio1

1.Reducing the browser zoom level distorts the elements in the screen that is the left and right panel comes one by one vertically, where increasing the zoom level works fine.

2.And I am having a header with two sections. Top section will be always visible in the screen even when the user scrolls down. Now the buttons in the bottom part of the header are getting hidden behind the top section of header when i set back the zoom level to 100%, this also happens when I scroll to the bottom of the screen and then the vertical scroll-bar disappears on any scenario.

Screenshot with hidden header buttons : http://www.freeimagehosting.net/2eq68

Comment: No screenshot what I can see?

Comment: And no source. The MVC is not important. The HTML, CSS and possibly Javascript is.

Answer (score 1):

Using browser zoom will often break your site depending on what CSS and HTML you have used. Using specific pixel values and even % sometimes for sizes will cause issues, font sizes and weights will cause issues too (browsers don't have the same fine-grain control on fonts that Desktop Applications usually do).

Depending on the site design, your best bet is to try and develop the site to be a fluid layout.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see, especially from a  screenshot. Much better to link to an example if you want full help.

I would say it's a CSS issue most likely and that you should check if you are using pixels rather than %.

You could put a sample on JS fiddle so people can help debug, it's pretty difficult if not impossible with that screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, the width of few areas should be fixed in pixels. This is a user decision where to apply what. If fluid layout is used then most of the areas are fixed in %. However, you will find that very less content appears in this layout. Whereas in fixed layout, the areas are fixed in pixels which are independent of resolution.

Hope, this will clear your ideas.